# Windows cannot find 'env.' make sure you typed the name correctly and try again

Tags: clickonce

When I initiate my click once application I get the above error. The click one application works well on all other machines. It also worked well on this machine a 32bit windows 7 enterprise computer. But recently it's been throwing the above error. Any ideas

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a ClickOnce problem, but a problem with what ClickOnce is launching.

Your application appears to be dependent on a 'thing' (library/resource?) called 'env'  [(is it this?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env).  This possibly should be registered in the registry on your machine, or as a local environment variable, yet for some reason now isn't - hence the problem only appearing on your machine.

It would be worth investigating the other machines to determine what they consider 'env' to be.